# How will Google treat my site if 90% of the URLs redirect and the internal links still point to the old URLs?

Tags: google-search, redirects, 301-redirect, web-crawlers, website-design

Our newly redesigned website version has so many redirects, because there were so many structural errors, SEO issues, and thin content.

- 90% of the URLs on the Website redirect.
- Total number of indexed pages is 2,290.
- There are no chained redirects.
- The site is not internally linking to the good URLs. (that's one of reason to redesign)

How Google will treat that?

Comment: Do you mean that the URLs are changed or you switched from http to https?

Answer (score 1):

Sites get rearranged all of the time, some for the better, some for the worse.

Use a 301 Permanent Redirect.  This way Google will understand that you want it to update it's index to use the new URLs, not the old ones.  Assuming your restructuring directs users to better content, you should see better performance in the long run.  In the short run, you might see a drop while Google reindexes and reevaluates your site and looks at user responses, bounces, and Google's own periodic testing of SERP positions.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be fine for SEO to continue to link to your old URLs.  However, you should start converting all the links on your site to the new URLs.

- Internally linking to URLs that redirect isn't best practice.  It isn't very common.
- Users will make two requests instead of one for each link they click on your site.
- Similarly, search engine crawlers will have to fetch twice as many URLs to get your pages. The old style URLs will get crawled far more often than they would if you changed the links.

You don't have to change all the URLs right away.  If it is a difficult thing to do, I would suggest tackling it over the next few weeks or months.